# In R, get a frequency distribution of IDs by count of distinct / unique categorical (factor) attribute

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

**Background**

I've got a dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a", "b", "c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d"),
                 manufacturer = c("ferrari","ferrari","porsche", "bugatti", "lamborghini","aston martin","lotus","koenigsegg","pagani","ford","mclaren","mercedes benz"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> df
   ID  manufacturer
1   a       ferrari
2   a       ferrari
3   a       porsche
4   b       bugatti
5   c   lamborghini
6   c  aston martin
7   c         lotus
8   c    koenigsegg
9   d        pagani
10  d          ford
11  d       mclaren
12  d mercedes benz
```

It's a little table of wealthy people (`ID`) and the `manufacturer`s of supercars they own. Some nice rides in here ️

**The problem**

I want to make a frequency table of the number of distinct/unique manufacturers owned by a given `ID`. In other words: how many IDs have *n* number of manufacturers?

So take `ID` = **a**, for instance: this person has three rows (corresponding to 3 cars), but only 2 distinct manufacturers -- he's got 2 Ferraris. (Must be nice.)

Basically I'd be looking for something roughly like this:

```
> [some R code]

count_manuf   count_ID
          1          1 
          2          1
          3          0 
          4          2
```

To explain that output in plain English:

- 1 `ID`, **b**, has 1 distinct `manufacturer`
- 1 `ID`, **a**, has 2 distinct `manufacturer`s
- 0 `ID`s have 3 distinct `manufacturer`s
- And 2 `ID`s, **c** and **d**, each have 4 distinct manufacturers.

In my "real" dataset, which has millions of rows, I don't actually know the upper limit of who has the most distinct manufacturers. Could be 4, could be 40. So I don't want the code to pre-specify anything; I'd just like it to go as high as it goes in the data.

**What I've tried**

I'm trying to mess with this `dplyr` code:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(manufacturer = (length((manufacturer)) > 0)) %>%
  count(manufacturer)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  manufacturer     n
  <lgl>        <int>
1 TRUE             4
```

But it just ends up giving the total number of `ID`s -- correct, but not what I need.

I've read other thread about getting frequencies of categorical variables, but none that group by ID. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table` (, which can handle data frames with millions of rows efficiently):

```
setDT(df)
df[, uniqueN(manufacturer), by = .(ID)][, .N, keyby = .(V1)]
#    V1 N
# 1:  1 1
# 2:  2 1
# 3:  4 2
```

here `V1` is the count of unique `manufacturer`s, and `N` is the count of unique `ID`s.

Comment: This worked really, really fast on the real dataset. Thanks so much. Doing some tallying to check a correct count but I think this is gonna be what I go with. Stand by.

Comment: Question: what will this do with `NA` values in the `manufacturer` row? I ask because while the sum of unique `ID`s comes out correct when I run this on the real data, I get slightly different values of  `ID` for number of distinct `manufacturer` than I had in an older calculation.

Comment: by default, `uniqueN` counts `NA`s as a unique value. If you want to ignore `NA`,  use `uniqueN(manufacturer, na.rm=TRUE)` instead.

Comment: That's *perfect*, right on the money, aligned with previous total sums and blazing fast. You win the evening 

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the zeros then maybe

```
setNames(
  data.frame(
    table(
      aggregate(manufacturer~ID,data=unique(df),FUN=length)$manufacturer
    )
  ),
  c("count_manuf","count_ID")
)

  count_manuf count_ID
1           1        1
2           2        1
3           4        2
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` way

```
df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(count_manuf = n()) %>%
  count(count_manuf, name = "count_ID") %>%
  tidyr::complete(count_manuf = 1:4, fill = list(count_ID = 0))
    
  count_manuf count_ID
        <int>    <int>
1           1        1
2           2        1
3           3        0
4           4        2
```

Comment: On that last line `tidyr::complete(count_manuf = 1:4, fill = list(count_ID = 0))`, what if I don't know the upper limit (the 4) in advance?

Comment: @logjammin `tidyr::complete(count_manuf = 1:max(count_manuf), fill = list(count_ID = 0))` will work.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d"),
  manufacturer = c("ferrari", "ferrari", "porsche", "bugatti", "lamborghini", "aston martin", "lotus", "koenigsegg", "pagani", "ford", "mclaren", "mercedes benz"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df |>
  count(ID, manufacturer) |>
  count(ID)
#>   ID n
#> 1  a 2
#> 2  b 1
#> 3  c 4
#> 4  d 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

in Base R you can use the `table` function:

```
data.frame(table(rowSums(table(unique(df)))))
  Var1 Freq
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    4    2
```

where `var1` is the count for unique manufacture's and `Freq` is the count of unique ID's
If you need the 3 to be 0, then you will have to transform the results to a factor as shown below:

```
s <- rowSums(table(unique(df)))
data.frame(table(factor(s, seq(max(s)))))

  Var1 Freq
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    0
4    4    2
```

Comment: In my real data, I have many columns, not just the 2. In your code, how would I pick out the `manufacturer` column specifically for the `rowSums` operation? Just by replacing `unique(df)` with `unique(df$manufacturer)` ??

Comment: @logjammin do `unique(df[c('ID', 'manufacturer')])`

Comment: Hm strange, getting this: `Error in df[c("ID", "manufacturer")] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: @logjammin you must have named your data differently. the name of your data in not `df`. Note that in my case `df` is the name of the data. use `unique(your_dataset[,c('ID', 'manufacturer')])` replace `your_dataset` with the correct variable

Comment: lmao i'm dumb -- you're absolutely right, I forgot to change the df name.